# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una cantidad de registros en un data table sin que me los cargue todos al inicio en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, html5, bootstrap, php7, laravel-blade

Tengo una base de datos con una única tabla que tiene miles de registros. Entonces en la vista blade tengo una data table que es un componente de la plantilla adminlte que integré con Laravel. En el controlador obtuve los registros de esta forma:

```
    $proyectos = DB::table('proyectos_inv')->paginate(50);
    return view('home',['proyectos' => $proyectos]);
```

Y lo mostré en la vista blade normalmente con un @foreach.
Resulta que el data table de la vista carga el siguiente script

```
  <script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Lo que sucede es que el paginado no funciona como imaginaba, lo que hace es cargar los primeros 50 registros como en este caso pero no los carga todos. Cuando elimino la función

> paginate

lo que hace el navegador es cargar todos los registros y cuando termina es que pagina. Existe alguna forma para que de entrada me cargue solo la cantidad de registros que quiero y no como lo está haciendo?

Esta tabla solo es de prueba pues la verdadera tiene millones de registros y en la práctica no es efectivo esperar a que descargue todos para poder paginar automáticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `chunk`. Este método recupera una pequeña porción de los resultados a la vez y posteriormente puedes paginarlos. Míralo y si tienes alguna duda vuelve por aquí.
Tienes información en la documentación   [Resultados fragmentados](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#chunking-results)

```
 $proyectos = DB::table('proyectos_inv')->paginate(50);
return view('home',['proyectos' => $proyectos]);
```

y en tu blade

```
 @foreach($proyectos->chunk(50) as $fila)
    @foreach($fila as $item)
        {{ $item->columna_name1 }}
        {{ $item->columna_name2 }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach

 {{ $proyectos->links() }}
```

Comment: Ahora me da error cuando voy a mostrar en la plantilla blade. Este es el codigo en controlador:  $ine_puebla = DB::table('ine_puebla')->orderBy('id')->chunk(50, function($ine)
            {
                foreach ($ine as $ines)
                 {
                 }

            });
        return view('home')->with('ine_puebla ',$ine_puebla);

Comment: Edito la respuesta

Comment: Lo hice exactamente así y ahora con  el **paginate(50)** solamente me saca 50 registros de la base de datos. Si elimino el **paginate(50)** entonces me da error. `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::chunk(), 1 passed in C:\laragon\www\inepuebla\storage\framework\views\b4b73467ff7e149cad3d6a4f470810da83c3ed7f.php on line 26 and exactly 2 expected (View: C:\laragon\www\inepuebla\resources\views\admin\partials\home-section\data-table.blade.php)`

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código de tu controlador y el código que utilizas en blade?

Comment: Ya logré encontrar una solución para esto se hace la ejecución del lado del servidor. Encontré un proyecto ejemplo. Dejo la url.
Muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron.
[https://w3path.com/how-to-install-yajra-datatables-with-laravel-6-application-e-g/][1]